# Retrieve multiple API's using ID

Tags: ajax, json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 APIs which I want to use simultaneously, API1 and API2.

API2 deliver news feeds to API1, while API1 handles all the content in a list form.  This means that if any list in API1 is clicked on, it will it will retrieve the the news feeds from API2 using an ID that has been defined.

Who can help me out here?  I am stuck.  The screenshot of my code is here: http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/2API.jpg

Thanks so much.

Comment: Looks like you need to wire up a *click* event and pass *contentId*, but it's hard to tell.  Can you provide more info?  Are you using some Javascript that you could post?

Comment: Hi dbaseman, the sample of my code is here. i print screen for a proper understanding: http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/2API.jpg

Comment: Thanks, but that's just some JSON, I still don't understand how your code is functioning.  Are you using some kind of framework (MVC?).  How are you rendering the news feed into markup?

Comment: Am using a Sencha touch 2 framework, In line24, you can see: url:'API 1' this is were i dropped my json. now i have a second json (API 2) which i will like to retrieve information using contentID. so that (example) when you click on force india lament lost time (refer to the pic) it will grab the news from the API2 using its contentID.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Sencha documentation here (under *Digging In*):  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app

You need to add a listener and a detail panel to your configuration, using this code (reference to contentId is not needed, you just need to pull the **description** property -- which contains the content -- from the original feed):

```
detailCard: {
    xtype: 'panel',
    scrollable: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true
},

listeners: {
    itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
        this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('description'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dbaseman, int he this example,  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app  in this example, they are calling a single API which all the description property and everything is in the same API. in my own case, i have 2 API's the second API holds the description to the first API... when you click on the list in API1, the contentID should be able to go to API2 and retrieve the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you manually listen to your list (which is fetched from API 1) `itemtap` event.

In your controller, there's should be something like:

```
refs: {
  bloglist: 'blog list'
},

control: {
  bloglist: {
    itemtap: 'fetchAPI2'
  }
},
fetchAPI2: function (list,index,target,record){
  id = record.get('contentId'); //this is your id for using API2.
  Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            scope: this,
            url: API2_URL,
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            params: {your params for API2 here},

            callback: function(success,result) {
                           // whatever you want to do here
            }           
        });
}
```

Comment: hi Thiem Nguyen, Am still confused, which part of my code should i insert the code you gave me? help me out pls:

Comment: Hi Thiem, i dont mind the controller, all i want is let it be grabbing the exact content using the contentID. but i dont know how to add up the code you gave me to my own codes to get it work

Comment: there's no way to call 2 API simultaneously through your store's proxy because it cannot be sure that your API 1 task is completed because calling the second one. The only way to do it (and seems quite clean), is to process your API2 manually through this in your Store: `listeners: {load: function(){// call your API2 here;}}`